# Where is the camera in the A320?

Tags: airbus-a320, cabin, camera

On the A320 family there are circuit breaker panels in the cabin between the exits. On the 2000VU panel there is a "camera" circuit breaker (C5 position):

[image]

<sup>Top: [Source](https://www.l3cts.com/training-systems/maintenance-products/virtual-maintenance-trainer) -- Bottom: [A320 CCOM](https://www.scribd.com/doc/120834010/CABIN-CREW-MANUAL) p165 -- Right: [A320 CCOM](https://www.scribd.com/doc/120834010/CABIN-CREW-MANUAL) p166</sup>

Which camera is it related to?

Comment: I believe, but have no evidence, that it's an option for one that looks out the front windshield, dashcam style. It was apparently a thing in the 1980s. Cockpit next to it is for United Channel 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an option for a tail mounted camera for the passenger entertainment system (PES). It's the [same one](https://www.securaplane.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/CMX-series-cameras.pdf) they use on widebody jets, but it's not hooked up to the cockpit for taxi purposes.

Airbus [press release](http://www.airbus.com/newsroom/news/en/2009/08/airbus-corporate-jet-centre-outfits-third-acj-with-vip-cabin.html) says

> Designed for a private customer, this cabin seats just over 30 passengers and includes such features as touch-screen technology, advanced passenger entertainment and communications, plus a tail-mounted camera.